# Redis ETIMOUT... How many reasons will cause this?

Tags: node.js, redis

I'm running Redis on Linux and for a period of time an error occured below in the log:

```
{ Error: Redis connection to xxx.yyy.zzz.ttt:6379 failed - connect ETIMEDOUT xxx.yyy.zzz.ttt:6379
    at Object.exports._errnoException (util.js:1020:11)
    at exports._exceptionWithHostPort (util.js:1043:20)
    at TCPConnectWrap.afterConnect [as oncomplete] (net.js:1086:14)
  code: 'ETIMEDOUT',
  errno: 'ETIMEDOUT',
  syscall: 'connect',
  address: 'xxx.yyy.zzz.ttt',
  port: 6379 }
```

I checked username and password, it seems everything goes right with me.
I wanna know roughly:

1) How many reasons will cause this?

2) What suggestions do you have to fix that?

Comment: `telnet xxx.yyy.zzz.ttt 6379` ?

Comment: No, I just hid my real IP.

Comment: No, I meant, what is the output of above command ? I guess, above command will not let you connect.

Comment: I think, redis is running on loopback (`127.0.0.1`) interface, and you are trying to connect to non-loopback ip address ?

Comment: @xqMogvKW Did you ever figure this out?  I am running into the same issue.